# VB6 How to detect sended key will be written in a textbox

Tags: vb6, key, send

How to detect sended key will write in a textbox?
for example:
i send "W" to a program which is active
how can i detect that "W" is written?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you send the "W" to a program....
If you mean if you actually type, you can use **_KeyDown**, **_KeyUp** or **_KeyPress** events of the textbox..

```
Private Sub Textbox_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  If KeyAscii = Asc("W") then Call MsgBox("Yes 'W' pressed")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = vbKeyW And ((Shift And vbShiftMask) = vbShiftMask) Then Call MsgBox("Yes 'W' pressed")
End Sub
```

OR you need to track changes using the **_Change** event, which ofcourse is a lot more work as you'll need to store the previous text and compare it with the current text, and see if a 'W' has been added. But you have to take into account that people might actually paste more than one letter.

```
Private Sub TextBox_Change()
  If Instr(TextBox.Text, "W")>0 Then
    If Instr(TextBox.Tag, "W") = 0 Then
      Call MsgBox("Yep 'W' added")
    Else
     'run down the Text along with the Tag and see if a 'W' is present at the same location
    End If
  End If
  TextBox.Tag = TextBox.Text
End Sub
```